# Returning a pointer to an array of ints in c++ (converted from string) - "invalid conversion" error

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, return

Header:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

int i[8];

#endif
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std

int main(){

int *test;
string bits = "10011011";

*test = func(bits);     //        ERROR    2   HERE
                        //my goal here is to have a pointer in main that
                        //points to the 1 address of the global var array i
}                       //if im totally missing the point and there is a 
                        //better way to do this please let me know
```

Function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std

int *func(string str){

int l = str.size();
int *ptr;

for(int k=0; k < l; ++k){
    i[k] = s[k] - '0';
}
*ptr = i;             // ERROR    1    HERE
return ptr;           
}
```

Hi all,

When I attempt to compile the above code, I get two errors as labeled. They are:

Error 1: invalid conversiopn from int* to int
Error 2: invalid conversion from int to *int

It seems I must have a fundamental understanding of what I am working with here. Am I not setting *ptr to point at the first memory address of the array i[]? Why is the compiler telling me that I am trying to set the value of the pointer to the value of i[]? I want to set the value of the pointer to the ADDRESS of i[]. If I add an & I get the same error.

Error 2 obviously follows error 1. It is the same error, just backwards.

My question is, then, what the heck am I doing wrong when I am trying to point *ptr in func() at the array i[]? I DID try finding the answers elsewhere to no avail.

Thanks.

edit: this code is a rough transcription of the original (from another PC), so if you try to compile it and there are typos I apologize.

Comment: Yes, you have a misunderstanding.  You are de-referencing a pointer, and trying to assign a pointer value to that.  Just "test = func().. and ptr = i". Not sure what the point is of func().  Also, naming an array as "i" probably not a good convention.

Comment: So what am I missing. Is it not true that *prt is the pointER and i[] is the pointEE?    --- Upon further review, it seems I am telling the pointer to store the value that it is currently pointing at into i[]. Is that the proper interpretation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int *ptr;` declares a pointer to `int`, so `ptr` is a pointer: a variable that stores the memory location of some `int`.  Currently it doesn't point to anything in particular, just some random place in memory that you probably don't own.

`*ptr` dereferences `ptr`, so `*ptr` is the `int` that `ptr` points to.

When you do `*ptr = i;` you are attempting to set the `int` pointed to by `ptr` equal to `i`, which is an array of 8 `int`s.  In this context, the array decays into a pointer to its first element, so you're attempting to set an `int` equal to an `int*`, hence the error.

This should just be `ptr = i;`, but even that isn't necessary, since you could just `return i;` and `i` would decay into a pointer to the first element of the array.

Similarly, `*test = func(bits);` attempts to set the `int` pointed to by `test` equal to the pointer returned by `func`.  It should just be `test = func(bits);`, in which case the address that `test` contains will become the one that `func` returned.  In this case `test` will point to the first element of `i`.

Comment: Thanks Miles. This does a good job of outlining my confusion. I got a little lost in the semantics of pointers but I figured it out. Thanks again.